# How to display a dynamically generated webpage to the new tab?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have generated a webpage dynamically in code behind. How can load and display it on user desktop?(c#, asp.net)
here is my code:

```
       StringBuilder strHtm = new StringBuilder();


        strHtm.Append("<html>");
        strHtm.Append(Environment.NewLine);

        strHtm.Append("<head>");
        strHtm.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        strHtm.Append("<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">");
        strHtm.Append(Environment.NewLine);

       strHtm.Append("</head>");
        strHtm.Append(Environment.NewLine);

        strHtm.Append("<body>");
        strHtm.Append(Environment.NewLine);

         //some code here reading from datatable

        strHtm.Append("</body>");
        strHtm.Append(Environment.NewLine);

        strHtm.Append("</html>");
        strHtm.Append(Environment.NewLine);
```

Now how can I load it in browser new tab or window?

Comment: You cannot **push** the page. You need a link (`<a href="mypage" target="_blank">load</a>`) which a visitor clicks to load your page in a new window/tab (depends on browser settings).

Comment: you mean i should save the webpage then create a link?

Comment: You should serve the page when a user clicks the link to it.

Comment: can you clear it with an example?

Comment: is there Something like  ::        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(strHtm.tostring());

Answer (score 1):

1. add another asp page
2. add a  PlaceHolder to newly created asp page
3. remove html,head,body tags
4. finally add this line of code in page_load

   ```
   PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(strHtm.ToString().Trim()))
   ```